# A possible shot in the dark - Seaward HAL-104 Tester experience?

Tags: serial, communication, testing, manufacturing

This post might be a shot in the dark, but has anyone here had any experience with the Seaward HAL-104 tester and its remote command protocol functionality? Or perhaps know someone who has? There is likely a better place to post this, however, this was the first place I thought of.

I am currently in an electrical engineering internship at a manufacturing company exploring the feasibility of developing a communication system through a standard (rs-232) serial interface on the HAL-104 that can communicate with our internal network. Somewhat unsurprisingly, there is little to no documentation on this functionality other than in the HAL-104 manual and [this](https://www.seaward.com/gb/support/manufacturing/hal-series/faqs-and-articles/653-how-to-downloand-hal-104/) page from Seaward's website, in which the download link for an sssprotocol.zip file containing example and support code and text leads to a 404 page.

If anyone has any advice or can point me in the right direction that'd be great. Thank you.

Comment: Contact sales support

Comment: I really hope someone takes the shot,in the dark,, oops,, may not. Anyway, the [pdf file](https://www.seaward.com/gb/support/pdf/653/) leads to [their webpage](https://www.seaward.com/gb/enquiry/) to Make an Enquiry. tips: Not reviling "internship" is not a moral or legal issue, say new and in charge of that task, which is true. Since, that is a capital equipment, you need to ask your superior about the "line of contact". Be brave, someone gets lost anyway by not doing or wrong doing, but not so much by doing wrong after trying hard.

Answer (score 3):

**google search result**

https://docs.rs-online.com/89a1/0900766b80efdbdc.pdf

p80 show the Serial port settings with 2(?) start bits and 1 stop bit. Xon Xoff 9600 and up

p104 starts with the 11 character command protocol.

Comment: Wow! Good job Tony, don't you go have some rest? :-)

Comment: Yes, sorry I haven't checked back in a few days I half forgot I posted this...I had already found the manual and customer support was somewhat helpful. Those two start bits are posing an issue now, however...seems strange that there would be two start bits when most serial connections today (as far as I know) use only one. Is there any way around this?

Comment: I don't know . ask Seaward on this awkward protocol. service@seaward.co.uk